# Drupal 7 Showing a Block next to a Node, when a Node has a Field with a certain Value

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-webform

I'm trying to show a Block (Webform) next to a Node, but only when the Node has a Field with a certain value.

An example is:

- The Node is a Restaurant
- The Block is a 50% off booking form (Webform)
- The Block is only shown where the Restaurant has a Field_50%_Off value equal to "Yes"

What (I think) I need is the php code to place into the Block visibility criteria. That is, only show this block when the following php code is true.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use node reference URL module and capture the field value of discount offered, this field can be hidden from display but, can be passed to the webform.

You can also explore context and reference entity modules.